# Running applications within PowerShell window

Tags: powershell, command-line, window, command-prompt

I'm trying to move away from Command Prompt, because it's a dead-end, over to PowerShell (ISE). I haven't figured out how to run command-line applications within the PowerShell (ISE) window. Everytime I use Start-Process a Command Prompt window appears (and disappears). I've seen some people suggest -Wait and -NoNewWindow but those haven't worked for me so far.

```
Start-Process MyApplication.exe
```

This starts Command Prompt, runs the application and disappears. PowerShell remains responsive.

```
Start-Process MyApplication.exe -Wait
```

This starts Command Prompt, runs the application and disappears. PowerShell doesn't get responsive until Command Prompt has exited.

```
Start-Process MyApplication.exe -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

This results in the following:

Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system can not find the file specified.

Comment: Try with the full path to the .exe. Or if it is at the current path use .\MyApplication.exe

Comment: I added the .\ to the beginning of the file name and it worked, but why?

Comment: I added the response as an answer. Please mark it if you think that answers this comment and your question.

Comment: It does but what about PowerShell ISE?

Comment: @HelloWorld, you might also like to check out ConEmu. PowerShell runs nicely in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` in PowerShell represents the current directory. This is to ensure that a user is not fooled into running a malicious executable at a folder specified by the `$env:Path` environment variable.

From the [about_Command_Precedence](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848304.aspx) help content:

> As a security feature, Windows PowerShell does not run executable (native) commands, including Windows PowerShell scripts, unless the command is located in a path that is listed in the Path environment variable (`$env:path`) or unless you specify the path to the script file.
>
> To run a script that is in the current directory, specify the full path, or type a dot (`.`) to represent the current directory.
>
> For example, to run the `FindDocs.ps1` file in the current directory, type:
>
> ```
>    .\FindDocs.ps1
> ```

Comment: This works in PowerShell but PowerShell ISE starts Command Prompt which then runs the application.

Comment: ISE is not a console host per se. It is a WPF app emulating console experience. So, the native commands behave differently there. But, the concept of .\ does not change between console and ISE.

Comment: Yes, the .\ works but the application doesn't get run inside ISE. The thing is that I'm working with applications that rely on Unicode and the Win32 console (Command Prompt/Windows PowerShell) doesn't handle it but I've been told that ISE does support Unicode and therefore I need to run the application inside ISE.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. ISE supports unicode but like I said it is not a console host but just a WPF application.