# Using Scrapy with Windows Powershell

Tags: powershell, scrapy

I'm unable to use scrapy commands via the Windows Powershell however I can use it via python using `execute` from `scrapy.cmdline`.

When I type anything beginning with `scrapy`, the 'open with' dialogue window pops up asking which program I'd like to use to open the file 'scrapy', which contains the following:

```
#!C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\Scripts\python.exe

from scrapy.cmdline import execute
execute()
```

I've tried: 
adding a `.` ahead of scrapy as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502118/running-applications-within-powershell-window)
adding `python` ahead of commands [suggested here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scrapy-users/0SUEqEwWUxA/RbkpdeSSL-wJ)
all of the above in cmd instead of PS

When I use scrapy through the Python interpreter everything functions correctly, does anybody have any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

I'm using PS version 2.0, Python 2.7.6 on Windows 7.

Comment: The `#!` syntax inside a file does nothing in Windows; which program is used to open a file depends only on the filename extension. Trying to run a file with no extension, e.g. `"scrapy"` will always prompt for which program to open it with. Even if you put `.\ ` in front, as that just makes sure you point to the extensionless file that you mean to. When you say you "tried adding python ahead of commands" what do you mean precisely, and what happened when you did that? What if you try naming your file `scrapy.py` or `scrapy.pyw`?

Comment: To begin with there aren't any files, so I don't anything to rename. I wanted to use a the scrapy command `scrapy startproject myproject` to begin a new project, it should create a series of project files. But instead this is when the 'open with' dialogue box appears and when I select a program the 3 lines of code mentioned in my question appear. Using the equivalent command in python execute(['scrapy','startproject','myproject']) creates all the 6 or so files and a new directory correctly as it's describe in its docs.

Comment: I tried `python scrapy startproject myproject` this gave `[Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you have `c:\Python27\Scripts\` folder in your `PATH` environment variable (`$env:PATH` to find out) - depends on your Python version, of course, it may be in that Enthought Canopy folder path, for instance.

When you type `scrapy`, Windows is finding the scrapy file (which you don't know exists, and that's why you say "there aren't any files") and trying to run it, but can't because it has no extension.

You are prompted to open it in a program, and you choose a text editor, and see the content (because there is a file). Instead you could choose to open it with Python - e.g. browsing to the `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\Scripts\python.exe` file and choosing that. Or `c:\python27\python.exe` if you have that.

To fix it without having to choose a file, you need to specify both where the Python interpreter is and where the scrapy file is, e.g.

`python scrapy startproject myproject` has to become something like

`C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Python27\Scripts\scrapy startproject C:\Users\username\Documents\projects\myproject`

(You will have to find out where Python.exe and `scrapy` are on your system. I am deliberately ignoring the Enthought path you show because I don't know anything about how it installs, and what folders it uses).

Edit: I suggest not changing the PATH because it might unintentionally break other things, and instead creating a wrapper for the scrapy launcher:

1. Rename `Scripts\scrapy` to `Scripts\scrapy-helper`
2. Create a file named `Scripts\scrapy.bat` with the content

   `C:\Python27\python.exe c:\Python27\Scripts\scrapy-helper %*`

With the correct paths for your system. When you type `scrapy` at the command prompt, Windows/PowerShell will find it, run it as a batch file, call the right Python to run the right scrapy script, and pass any parameters you used through to Python.

Comment: You were completely correct! Is the problem that the `..\Scripts` folder is in the `PATH` environment or is it that the `scrapy` file is there?
I tried renaming `scrapy` with `.py` and `.pyw`, deleting it, and moving it to my desktop but it always produces `The term 'scrapy' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program..`

Comment: It's hard to say which is the problem - presumably someone created the installers to put `Scripts` into the `PATH` because they needed it there, and someone put `scrapy` in the `Scripts` folder because they needed it, and who knows why it wasn't written to be Windows compatible. I have updated my answer with a possible workaround.

Comment: The solution worked perfectly, thanks! For anybody stumbling across this with Canopy scrapy and python.exe are found in: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\Scripts